# AVCaptureSession recording audio only after 1 to 2 seconds delay

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am creating an Audio Video recording application for `MAC OSX` using `Objective-C` using `AVfoundation` class, the video starts to record at button click.

> There is an delay in audio record starting time approx 1 to 2 secs.

Here is the code i used to setup devices,

```
 deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];
mic = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
microphone_input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:mic error:&error];

if(!deviceInput){
    NSLog(@"Error Message: %@", error);
}

if ([session canAddInput:deviceInput]) {
    [session addInput:deviceInput];
}

if([session canAddInput:microphone_input]){
    [session addInput:microphone_input];
}
```

Record Video:

```
CMTime fragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid;
[aMovieFileOutput setMovieFragmentInterval:fragmentInterval];
[aMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:       [tempFileName stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mov"]] recordingDelegate:self];
```

**Please help me to identify the reason for delay in audio recording when start.**

Answer (score 2):

Creates an audio file at the location specified by the url parameter in the `initWithURL:settings:error:` method. If a file already exists at that location, this method overwrites it.

The preparation invoked by this method takes place automatically when you call record. Use  [`prepareToRecord`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008238-CH1-SW2) when you want recording to start as quickly as possible upon calling record.

Comment: As i already specified am recording video+audio using 'movieFileOutput',  is there any need to seperately implement the AVAudioRecord class to record audio properly.. Please clarify me. @VatsalRaval

Comment: Also i dont want separate audio file... the output should be a movieFile(Audio+Video).